# Adding `bool` to `float`

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I'm maintaining some code and came across this snippet:

```
int num = 0;
float sum = 0.0;
bool value[rows][cols]; //initialized elsewhere in the code
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        if(value[i][j] == true) {
            sum += value[i][j]; //shouldn't this be equivalent to "sum += 1;"
                                //as it is in the if block?
            num++;
        }
float ans = 1.0;
if(num > 12)
    ans = sum / num;
```

Is the guy who wrote this code originally doing something fiendishly clever here, or should `ans` always be `1`? As far as I can tell, `num` and `sum` should always be exactly the same value, no?

Comment: What is the type of `value`? For example any non-zero `int` will evaluate to `true` so `sum += value[i][j]` may not be equivalent to `sum += 1`.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified; `value` is a `bool`. Adding to question.

Comment: @Cyber 2 will not evaluate equal to `true` in this case (when using `==` instead of conversion to bool)

Comment: but shouldn't value[][] be filled with random bytes? this code is doing nothing at all... calculating the mean value of random?

Comment: "Fiendishly clever" often also means "unmaintainable".

Comment: @Cyber "any non-zero int will evaluate to true" - no, you are confusing the comparison against `true` and contextual conversion to `bool`.

Comment: Why not take a stroll with the debugger and find out for yourself?

Comment: I don't think `true` is specified in the C++ standard as specifically being equal to `1`, it might just need to be a non-zero value. I wouldn't rely on it. Also `== true` is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidYoung `true` is always converted to 1. See Shafik's answer below.

Comment: @Josh: Because it is in a part of the code that takes days to run even in release mode; have fun doing that in debug mode. I suppose I could have written some dummy arrays and tried it with that, but I really just wanted a sanity check to make sure I hadn't completely lost my marbles.

Comment: @Exceptyon: `value` is initialized elsewhere; I just included that line to specify the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will the same as `sum += 1` since a `true` value will be converted to `1` this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `4.9` *Floating-integral conversions* which says:

> If the source type is bool, the value
>   false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one.

The additive operators will cause the *usual arithmetic conversions* to be performed on their operands. Which in this case will be covered by this case:

> Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.

and we know that `E1 += E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 + E2` from section `5.17` *Assignment and compound assignment operators* which says:

> The behavior of an expression of the form E1 op = E2 is equivalent to E1 = E1 op E2 except that E1 is
>   evaluated only once.[...]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not *fiendlishly* clever because the `if` statement is still present.

To be clever, one would do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
       sum += value[i][j];  // Add 1 if true, 0 if false.
       num += value[i][j];  // Add 1 (increment) if true, add 0 if false
    }
}
```

The assumption is that a `bool` type will convert to 1 if `true`, and 0 if `false`.  This is how things were done in the dawn of computers.

If the `true` evaluates to some nonzero value other than 1, this code will not work correctly.

Upon further analysis, the `sum` and `num` will have the same value at the end of the loops.
So, only use `num` and convert to `float` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If value is a (two-dimensional) array of `bool`, then this is equivalent with `sum += 1`. In contrast with what some people think, a comparison with `== true` is **not** the same as an implicit conversion to `bool` (e. g. in the context of an if statement's condition). Any integer not equal to `1` will be considered different from `true`.

Comment: Also, thinking a bit more about it, this is true for any integral type, not only `bool`.